# JAXB Integer and Long parsing

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an object structure that contains multiple numeric values:

```
@XmlTransient
public class Person
{
private Integer age;
private Long shoeSize;
public setAge(Integer age){...}
public getAge(){return age;}
...
}

public class Child extends Person
{
private Integer readingAge;
public setReadingAge(Integer readingAge){...}
public getReadingAge(){return readingAge;}
}

public class Team
{
private ArrayList<Child> children = new Arraylist<Child>();
...
}
```

So when I marshall the Child object the age is missed. There is a possability that age can be null so i cannot just add it as an int value.

The reasoning behind the @xmlTransient is due to i need the marshalling to marshall the whole document in alphabetical order. If i remove the transient the person elements are ordered then the child elements are added to the end.

So my questions are:
Is there anyway i can get the age recognised without it defaulting the value to 0?
Can I order the document as a whole without setting the transient flag?
I have tried to simplfy my example as the real example has 100's of elements

Target XML:

```
<Team>
    <Child>
        <age>5</age>
        <readingAge>25</readingAge>
        <shoeSize>1</shoeSize>
    </Child>
</Team>
```

But if age was null:

```
<Team>
    <Child>
        <readingAge>25</readingAge>
        <shoeSize>1</shoeSize>
    </Child>
<Team>
```

Marshalling class:

```
Child c = new Child(5, 9, 25);
Team t  = new Team();
t.getChildren().put(c);
if (getMarshaller() == null)
         {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Team.class);
            setMarshaller(context.createMarshaller());
         }

         StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
         getMarshaller().marshal(t, sw);
         String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

Comment: As you don't show how Person and Child objects are used in their respective containing classes it is difficult to see where your problem(s) are. Perhaps you add these classes (in reduced form) as well, and explain what should define the "alphabetical order".

Comment: I have problems to visualize the actual XML and how it should look like in the end - could you add an example for the actual and expected XML, please?

Comment: Also, what has the **Long** in the title got to do with your question? And you write **parsing** but the question speaks of "marshalling".

Comment: @laune my class contains Longs aswell as string and both exhibit the same behaviour.  I have added the other related classes also.

Comment: @Rhayene I have added some samples.

Comment: so the children shall be in alphabetical order? how do you sort them? do you sort the list beforehand? Maybe I still don't understand what you mean with the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when I marshall the Child object the age is missed. There is a
>   possability that age can be null so i cannot just add it as an int
>   value.

Correct, and that is the way to handle it if a `null` age should be marshalled and (later) unmarshalled as `null` again. *The absence of an element is the way a `null` value is represented.*

> Can I order the document as a whole without setting the transient
>   flag?

Yes, you can: the `ArrayList<Child> children` in class `Team` contains an *ordered* collection of `Child` objects, and they will be marshalled in this order, and (later) unmarshalled back again into the same list.

> I need the marshalling to marshall the whole document in alphabetical
>   order.

This is not something JAXB will do for you automatically. If, for instance, the `children` list should be ordered alphabetically, you need to sort it, e.g., by calling `Collections::sort` with a Team object's field `children` as its (first) parameter. (I can't provide an example since I don't see a String field, either in `Person` or in `Child`, not even in the XML example.)

**Edit**

> I only need the ordering where inheritance is concerned. E.g. `<age>
>   <readingAge> <shoeSize>`

Again, this is not something JAXB will do, and it is a very unusual requirement. (What is the purpose?) Probably your best option would be to override the Person getters in the Child class and define the ordering by annotating the class with

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"age","readingAge","shoeSize"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far. I only need the ordering where inheritance is concerned. E.g.
<age>
<readingAge>
<shoeSize>

If i dont mark the Person as transient i get as i believe it is starting the create the string from the Person object then bolting on the rest:
<age>
<shoeSize>
<readingAge>

Comment: So the only ordering i need to worry about is the Person and Child elements not the Team.

Comment: Ah - do you mean you need an ordering of the *XML elements* - age before readingAge before shoeSize?